# Could not preview project

Tags: actions-on-google

My project name is Mr. HTML Teacher and I've successfully submitted and it is accepted in ENGLISH language using trivia templates.
The project id is mr-html.
Now I am trying to add another language (French).
First, I added the language in Actions of the project and creates an Excel in french. But when I upload, it gives the following error: 
Could not preview project: mr-html Parameter: projectId

[image]

Comment: Please contact support: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/